# HTTPServer не полностью отдает файл при установке тайм аута в lxc контейнере

Tags: python-3.5, lxc

Есть скрипт выступающий в роле простого http сервера.
В попытке устранить зависание скрипта при залипшем коннекте клиента к серверу, я решил установить тайм аут сокета (возможно ошибочное решение). Но возникла другая проблема, которая в свою очередь воспроизводится только в LXC контейнере. Скрипт отдает тело не более 83.5 КБ - файлы больше режутся до этого размера.

На хостовых Ubuntu Desktop 16.04 x64 и OpenSUSE Tumbleweed x64 скрипт отвечает на запрос как положено.

Пробовал на нескольких конфигурациях:

1. Хост: Ubuntu server 16.04 x64 Контейнер: Ubuntu 16.04
2. Хост: Proxmox VE 4.3 Контейнер: Debian 8

Пример:

```
import http.server as http
class HTTPRequestHandler(http.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def __init__(self, reqest, cli_addr, server):
        self.timeout = 10.0
        super().__init__(reqest, cli_addr, server)

    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path == '/':
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/css')
            self.end_headers()
            with open("bootstrap.min.css", 'rb') as css:
                self.wfile.write(css.read())


http_server = http.HTTPServer(('', 8080), HTTPRequestHandler)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    http_server.serve_forever()
```